# Расчет максимально возможного количества одноадресных команд

Tags: архитектура

Все команды системы команд ЭВМ имеют длину L = 16 и при использовании прямой адресации адресуют объем памяти VОП  =128 (байт). Команды имеют одно или два поля адреса. Если имеется N = 2 двухадресных команд

Answer (score 1):

Так как адрес занимает 7 бит, то для двухадресных команд остается два бита. В два бита можно втиснуть 4 команды. При этом на другие уже не останется ничего. Если двухадресных команд 3, то все одноадресные будут иметь одинаковые первые два бита и их будет 128 штук (так как это освободившийся адрес). Отсюда вывод - кол-во одноадресных команд (максимальное) равно (4-N) * 128.